# Управление транзакциями в Spring

Tags: spring, spring-jpa

В проекте стали появляться следующие ошибки при удалении сущности с составным ключом:

```
No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot
reliably process 'remove' call
```

При этом такое происходит только при попытке вызова метода репозитория этой сущности, с другими все в порядке:

```
public interface RecordAttributeRepository extends
        PagingAndSortingRepository<RecordAttribute, RecordAttributePrimaryKey> {

    @Modifying // наличие или отсутствие аннотации не влияет ни на что
    void deleteByIdEntityNameAndIdEntityId(String idEntityName, String idEntityId);
}
```

сама сущность и ее PK выглядят так:

```
public class RecordAttribute {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RecordAttributePrimaryKey id;

    @Column(name = "attribute_value", nullable = false)
    private String value;
    ...
}


public class RecordAttributePrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "entity_name", nullable = false)
    private String entityName;

    @Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)
    private String entityId;

    @Column(name = "attribute_name", nullable = false)
    private String attribute;
    ...
}
```

ЧЯДНТ? Бины `JpaTransactionManager`, `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` создаются и существуют внутри контейнера, с остальными сущностями всё ок, версия спринга и орм - 4.2.0.

Comment: и `@Transactional` есть, где надо?

Comment: @Nofate вообще нет, но ставить пробовал. Я так и не залез в эту часть документации, но в большинстве случаев при установке `@Transactional` спринг валится при попытке обмотать прокси еще одной проксей.

Comment: Что-то не так. @Transactional как раз инжектирует сессию JPA в вызываемый метод (если у вас там в принципе аннотации транзакций включены, конечно). Может по стектрейсу погадаем?

Comment: @Nofate я так понял, что она автоматом инжектируется в методы репозиториев при включенном `@EnableTransactionManagement`. Стектрейс прямо сейчас не смогу привести, там надо будет костыль откатить

Comment: Ох уж эти новомодные штуки в спринге ) `@EnableTransactionManagement` [вроде как равносилен](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) `<tx:annotation-driven/>`. То есть объявлять транзакции через @Transactional нужно. Считаю, нужно покурить [16. Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)